# Problems creating OData proxy class - connecting to Azure using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, azure, odata

I hope anyone can help me.

My plan was to connect to Microsoft Azure with my iPhone application. I don't have any experiences using http requests with Objective C yet. So I searched all day long on how to use Azure with Objective C...
I found out that one should use OData to create a proxy class which should help to connect to Azure (http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/projects/odata-client-for-objective-c-%28ios-macos%29).

So I tried configuring like it says in OData's user guide. But I don't understand how to create a proxy class: I tried to compile the odatagen.xcodeproj but I got a `Range or index out of bounds` error.
However I typed this in Terminal:

```
./odatagen /uri=https://{serviceNamespace}.serverbus.windows.net /out= users/xyz/Documents[...] /auth=acs /u=myusername /p=mypassword /at=https://{serviceNamespace}.serverbus.windows.net /sn={serviceNamespace} /ups=no
```

(Of course replacing {serviceNamespace} with the name of my service namespace etc.)

Did I get all those parameters right? I get an mystical error saying `fileRange Error While moving xslt file: (null)`... :-(

Or am I totally wrong and connecting my app with Azure works with different tools?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could get it working with what you're doing, but Microsoft have done a lot of the hard work for you.  Take a look at the [Windows Azure Toolkit for iOS](https://github.com/microsoft-dpe/wa-toolkit-ios) on git hub, it's probably the best place to start.

Comment: hi knightpfhor, thank you for your response! do you have any experiences with this windows azure toolkit? i tried this before trying odata but didn't really get it to work. :( but i'll try again and then post my questions on this toolkit. ;-)

Comment: Personally, no, but I thought the toolkit included classes for working with the service bus.  I may have been wrong though.